# TypeScript: Infer type of callback function parameter

Tags: typescript

I am passing a callback function as a function parameter, and I need to know the type of this parameter. I don't want to define the type manually as it's too complicated.
VSCode can infer the parameter type, but how can I get a type alias?

Is there some methods like ReturnType and InstanceType that can do the job?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should correctly infer the type of `response`:

```
type AddProfileResponseType = 
  typeof onAddProfileDone extends (cb: (r: infer R) => any) => any 
    ? R 
    : never
```

If the library defines a type for the `onAddProfileDone` function. You should use it instead of `typeof onAddProfileDone`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=3&pln=7&pc=9#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYlEBjAFgJSgZwK4BsQwC8MA3jAIYBGSAXDJiAE4CWAdgOYC%20wwAZtqyQhmAe1YwxAQQAm0gAqMRvZrigARMVAAUSSnS2MsEMZih0EydFjwgAlEQB8MAG4jm0%20yW6hIsGfMVlVQxMY1ZTABVfIhhgGBhwaCUJVn8FJRV1TRgoAA8QKFZpTBgdPVLGOjZeKEYYNHtCJ3JWMEbm1tj4%20IB%20eq7uulYoZ1qgA)

---

Or even simpler:

```
type AddProfileResponseType = Parameters<Parameters<typeof onAddProfileDone>[0]>[0]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=84&pln=6&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYlEBjAFgJSgZwK4BsQwC8MA3jAIYBGSAXDJiAE4CWAdgOYC%20wwAZtqyQhmAe1YwxAQQAm0gAqMRvZrigARMVAAUSSnS2MsEMZih0EydFjwgAlEQB8MAG4jm0%20yW6hIsGfMVlVQxMY1ZTABVfIhg5ckZyAFtEKEZMAB44hOSQVIzwaCUJVn8FJRV1TQcAbQAGAF0ahqA)

Comment: Thanks the second one works for me! Didn't try the first version.